# Error 1064 (42000) Stumped on my create table

Tags: mysql

```
create table chgtaxes
  (
    po_no char(8) not null,
    change smallint not null,
    line_no smallint not null,
    stax_rate decimal(6,5) not null,
    utax_rate decimal(6,5) not null 
  );

create unique index chgtax_1 on chgtaxes (po_no, change, line_no);
```

I'm not sure where my issue is in this statement. It seems to be popping up on some other tables and I feel like the problems are related. Help Please!

Edit:

Here is the actual error:

[image]

Comment: When there is an error, please include the whole error as printed in your question. In this case it's a syntax error which would have given a rough idea as to where.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For us to help out with your question, we'll need more context: check out the guidelines on [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and include more steps on the code needed to reproduce the problem, the system you're working on, and what you've tried so far (including links to related questions). We'd like to help, but need you to help make this clearer!

Answer (score 0):

Found that there is a stark difference in the number of reserved words from the last time i built a database.  Was able to resolve my issues.